# Create autolayout view behind transparent NavigationBar

Tags: ios, xamarin

How to create a view (auto layout) which has a navigation bar (is transparent) and this view is behind navigation bar. See image

[image]

i tried in viewDidLoad

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = true;
EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
```

is C# code (Xamarin project).. 
IOs equivalent

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: what is the issue ? what you have tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when u set your root UINavigationController properties (e.g in appDelegate)

```
navigationController.NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(new UIImage(), UIBarMetrics.Default);
navigationController.NavigationBar.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
navigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = true;
```